# Alias/shortcut in windows explorer address bar

Tags: windows-explorer, address-bar

The question comes from when opening 'Run' in start menu (windows key+R) and enter system32 will open up an explorer and directly go to C:\WINDOWS\system32.
Q1: how to make my own alias, so when I enter photos, it brings me to c:\photos

Q2: Is there any way to use alias in windows explorer address bar similar to that? Say enter photos in address bar and go to c:\photos

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is no alias, it's just the Run dialog automatically looking in the directories given by the `PATH` environment variable. If you include `C:\` in your `PATH` then you should be able to type `photos` into the Run dialog and get an Explorer window in `C:\Photos` (not that I'd recommend having random personal directories in a location where you don't even have write access ... but anyway).

The explorer's address bar works differently, though. It can only start programs that are somewhere in the `PATH` with the current directory as their starting working directory. Well, and it can navigate to folders by full path, library name or to web pages.